# MS Access Connection String Error

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, ms-access-2013

Cannot open database ''. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt."

it appears after setting password on my Database. what should i do??

here is my code to path Database

```
 Private Sub Registration_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= |DataDirectory|\Accounts.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123;"
End Sub
```

i got this code in connectionstring.com but also same error appear.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this Code? And if it doesn't work, can you give the exact error message? If it doesn't recognize the database, You need to install access accdb driver. If it's corrupt, try to compact and repair database.

```
  con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" 
& Application.StartupPath() & "'\Accounts.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123;"
```

Comment: Forgot to tell you that when using Application.StartupPath(), your database should be in the same directory as your .exe. Which, in your case, is inside the debug folder.

Comment: thank you for reply sir but it didnt work. problem already in there. i already installed access accdb driver.

Comment: Can you give write down the exact error message? So you mean it does work without the password right?

Comment: By the way, I just noticed you're using MS Access 2013. You can check out this website, http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ for more information. The default encryption scheme for 2013 doesn't work on the current connectionstring you're using. In Access, click on options and choose 2007 encryption method.

Comment: i already used that code in the connectionstrings.com sir but same error appears.

Comment: Did you change the default encryption scheme?

Comment: Try to save your accdb database in 2007 format. It should work.

Comment: sir thank you it fixed but another error comes.

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Comment: Alright great, 1 solution at a time. Can you give me the exact connectiongstring you're using? This problem usually pops out if you didn't put the character @ before the path string. It's used to escape backslashes if you're using null terminating characters. If you still can't get this right, I suggest checking everything again before posting another question. For the time being, please do mark this thread as answered. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the full path of the database

```
Private Sub Registration_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= c:\Data\Accounts.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123;"
End Sub
```

Comment: is your database is really exists in the datadirectory?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do is go to datasource on left side. select the database that you want to connect right click on it and go to property in that first row will represent connection string. Try to use that string for the connection.

There is one example over here of msaccess database connection with vb.net in oledb.
Just check it. It will be surely helpful to you.

http://vb.ankwebsoft.in/msaccess-vb-oledb-connection.php